# Unable to execute the following query from Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database-connection, mariadb

I am trying to execute the following queries from Java.
The query looks like this and this is working perfectly fine when I am trying to execute this in Maria DB .

```
LOCK TABLE item_tree WRITE;
SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM item_tree WHERE item_id = 7; 
UPDATE item_tree SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt >= @myRight; 
UPDATE item_tree SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight; 
INSERT INTO item_tree(item_name, lft, rgt) VALUES('BLA', @myRight , @myRight + 1);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I have written the following piece of code for this purpose.

```
  try {
            DatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseConnection();
            Connection conn = dbConn.initiateConnection();

        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(Queries.queryInsertChildNode);
        stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(nodeId));
        stmt.setString(2,newNodeName);

        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(resultSet);

        dbConn.closeConnection(conn);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where  Queries.queryInsertChildNode = represents the above query.

It gives the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE item_tree SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE
>   rgt >= @myRight; UPDATE item_tree SET l'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do the following query for testing: `SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM item_tree WHERE item_id = 7; SELECT @myRight;` and post the result...maybe @myRight is not declared...

Comment: Is the table `ENGINE=MyISAM`?  Why?

Comment: @RickJames Sorry I didn't get your question. Can you please explain a little.

Comment: @Hackerman I did what you told me to do. As I already said before, this query is working perfectly fine. Even the query you told me to run is also running perfectly. I ran SELECT @ myRight := rgt FROM item_tree WHERE item_id = 7; SELECT @ myRight; It returned 13 which is the desired result.

Comment: Please provide the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE item_tree;`.  If it says `ENGINE=MyISAM`, then I will argue for switching to `InnoDB`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using Stored Procedure. I created a stored procedure which looks like the below code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`XXXX`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertChildNode`(IN `nodeId` INT, IN `newNodeName` VARCHAR(50))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

    Rollback;

START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT @myRight := rgt FROM item_tree WHERE item_id = nodeId;

    UPDATE item_tree SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt >= @myRight;
    UPDATE item_tree SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myRight;
    INSERT INTO item_tree(item_name, lft, rgt) VALUES(newNodeName, @myRight , @myRight + 1);

COMMIT;

END
```

And I called this stored procedure from java with the below code:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = null;
try {
    DatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseConnection();
    Connection conn = dbConn.initiateConnection();

    String SQL = "{call insertChildNode(?, ?)}";

    //CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call demoSp(?, ?)}");

    cstmt = conn.prepareCall(SQL);

    cstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(nodeId));
    cstmt.setString(2, newNodeName);

    cstmt.execute();

    System.out.println("Query executed...");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        cstmt.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```